# Google Apps Script will not run in cURL?

Tags: curl, google-apps-script

I can execute this URL (which is a Google Apps Script) from the Browser:

### https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyiZfWd10mmuaKPBF4zMMV4WJl_ZmLFrzCJCC_xZmviu-6z4lBS/exec

My goal is to send a GET to pushingbox that will then send the https:  Pushingbox seems to give the same results as cURL.  So for simplification, here is what I get from cURL:

```
curl https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyiZfWd10mmuaKPBF4zMMV4WJl_ZmLFrzCJCC_xZmviu-6z4lBS/exec
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?      service=wise&amp;passive=1209600&amp;continue=https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyiZfWd10mmuaKPBF4zMMV4WJl_ZmLFrzCJCC_xZmviu-6z4lBS/exec&amp;followup=https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyiZfWd10mmuaKPBF4zMMV4WJl_ZmLFrzCJCC_xZmviu-6z4lBS/exec">here</A>.
</BODY>
```

Why does it appear that when the HTTPS is sent from cURL it requires a login to run the Google Script?  I put the Share on the Google Script to "even anonymous can edit"

Is there a way to get cURL (and hence pushingbox) to work?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: When testing in a browser I get a login screen too... The answer below is right, you don't need to share the script, only the app itself.

Answer (score 5):

Adding the -L flag to curl will instruct it to follow the redirect:

```
curl -X GET -L https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyiZfWd10mmuaKPBF4zMMV4WJl_ZmLFrzCJCC_xZmviu-6z4lBS/exec
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: and for the POST query?